# Audio does not stop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My small app plays music when the user hits the play button, but I want the music to stop when the user clicks on the "next" button. I've tried different methods but I'm having a problem; can anyone help please? Please find attached the code. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)info {

    // This part takes us to the info page
    InfoPage *rab = [[InfoPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoPage" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:rab.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // This part plays the next page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    pagePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [pagePlayer setDelegate:self];
    pagePlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [pagePlayer play];

    //This will stop the music when turning page
    //[audioPlayer release];
    clicked = 0;
    [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

- (IBAction)next {

    // This part takes us to the next view
    Rabbana2 *rab = [[Rabbana2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Rabbana2" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:rab.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // This part plays the next page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    pagePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [pagePlayer setDelegate:self];
    pagePlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [pagePlayer play];

    //This will stop the music when turning page
    //[audioPlayer release];
    clicked = 0;
    [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

}

// This button plays the audio
- (IBAction)play {

    if(clicked == 0){
        clicked = 1;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rabbana1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


        [audioPlayer play];
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sstop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    else{
        [audioPlayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 

}

//If user does not do anything by the end of the sound set the button to start
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                        successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

// If user click on the next button while audio playing, Audio should stop
- (void) audioPlayerDidNotFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                                success: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        //[audioPlayer stop];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the `AVAudioPlayer` using the `-stop` method.  For more information, see the [AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-DontLinkElementID_28).  You would use this in the `-play` button action like this:

```
- (IBAction)play {
    if(clicked == 0){
    ...
    } else {
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [audioPlayer release];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i did add the code but still the same. it's not stopping the music.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you want to stop the audioPlayer when the user hits next but it continues to play. I noticed that you don't have [audioPlayer release] or [audioPlayer stop] in (IBAction)next. Try that and see if it stops the player when next is selected.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well i did add [audio release] and it does stop the music when i click on next, but when i click on back, the simulator crashes. I've enabled Zombie , and when it crashes it points me to the [audio release]. So i'm confused.

Comment: Are you also releasing the player in Dealloc as well? it might be the case that the player is being over-released. I usually set the following in Dealloc self.audioPlayer.delegate = nil and self.audioPlayer = nil;

Comment: I've tried to add your code, but it's showing a ***semantic error***